# Why do the Paladins want to kill jumpers?

Tags: jumper

The Paladins always try and kill the Jumpers for no reason other than they're "dangerous" which they have no evidence of -- so why do they insist on killing them instead of just leaving them alone?

Comment: After watching the film for 5 minutes, I wanted to kill them.

Comment: My second guess is *"to prevent a sequel"*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can somewhat infer from the name, the Paladins have a pseudo-religious hatred for Jumpers. If you listen to the way they talk about jumping, they believe that the Jumpers are using a power that only God should have access to.

They never give any *specific* reasons why this power is dangerous, but just looking at all the bad things one Jumper got up to it's not hard to imagine what a truly unscrupulous Jumper could do. To the Paladins, the power is unnatural and not meant for human consumption, and since they can't take it away from the Jumpers, in their religious fervor, they conclude that they have to kill them.

Comment: "*Only God should have the power to be all places at all times"*

Comment: of course the Paladin's have no issue with using this same power (un-naturally with tracking equipment) to destroy the Jumpers.  Fight fire with fire so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

In the book, one of the first things Davie does is rob a bank - partly because he doesn't believe he has other options.  He also speculates about finding others with the same talent, by looking at unsolved crimes.  If I recall, in the movie he goes somewhat farther in using the talent only to his own ends.  It may be that the order doesn't show what proof they might have that it is dangerous, but it wouldn't surprise me if they had some evidence, that there are those with the talent who have used it selfishly.

The specific reason why they are so sure of the danger of jumpers may be linked to how the Paladins were formed, or how a group found out about the teleporting, or to any number of real or suspected encounters with people who learned about the ability (and banded together) - there's no real way to know, but it is quite likely they have some evidence that is convincing to *them*.  It may have started with actual danger that was exaggerated and given religious overtones, or religion that encountered danger and screamed, 'unnatural'. And as long as they *believe* in the danger, of course they will only try to kill any jumpers first, and take any counterattacks as proof of aggression, and build up a deep, irrational, and eventually pseudo-religious belief that there is no other way to deal with Jumpers than by killing them.